# Is the "Vox Populi" badge working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I spent all my 40 votes today and didn't get the "Vox Populi" badge awarded :(

**Is this a bug or did I do something wrong? Any other possible reasons?**

Comment: [Related] [No Enlightened badge to go with Nice Answer on first-posted accepted answer?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5707)

Comment: Welp, you still don't have it, which is odd, it should've arrived by now. We don't see your individual votes, but I suspect you might've only done 39: [your profile stats](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/26548/numrok?tab=summary) say 1 vote today (right now; it's about to become tomorrow) but 40 this week. If you did 1 vote today... 39 of them this week must be not-today. Bear in mind answer voting has a slightly lower cap than question voting - IIRC you can vote on a max of only 30 answers, but a max of 40 questions.

Comment: i see that might have been the problem. it said that i couldnt vote anymore at some point, so probably the answer cap was reached?

Comment: @Numrok Yeah, it was probably the answer cap. Vote until you can't vote on questions *or* answers to be totally sure. Sucks that you got close but no cigar/badge. :(

Comment: @doppelgreener: i'm gonna get dat badge, dont worry 8)

Comment: @Numrok Congratulations on the badge! I see you chased it down and got it. :)

Comment: @doppelgreener: thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many badges don't get awarded the very moment you meet their criteria. Instead, they get checked and awarded periodically by scripts that run every few minutes or hours (sometimes *lots* of hours), according to how server-intensive the badge is to check for, and how often people get it.

You'll probably get the badge later today. If you don't get it for a whole day, *then* there's an issue.